# Mock IEnumerable<T> is returning null

Tags: c#, .net-core, moq, xunit.net

I am using XUnit unit tests for testing my API Controllers in .NET Core 2.1.  I am using MOQ for mocking my interfaced repositories.  Debugging my unit test when I do the setup it still comes out null before it even hits the controller.

I have tried constructing the result using `Returns` or `ReturnsAsync`.  Using a separate function to return a list or a `IEnumerable<T>`.

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPendingApprovals()
{
    var user = _serviceRepository.GetUserName(User);
    var userId = await _serviceRepository.GetUserID(user);

    var result = await _requestRepository.GetPendingApprovalsByApprover(userId);

    if (!result.Any()) return NoContent();

    return Ok(result);

}
```

Test

```
private Mock<IServiceRepository> mockServiceRepo;
private Mock<IRequestRepository> mockRequestRepo;
private ApprovalController controller;


public ApproverControllerTests()
{
    mockServiceRepo = new Mock<IServiceRepository>();
    mockRequestRepo = new Mock<IRequestRepository>();
    ILogger<ApprovalController> mockLoggerRepo = Mock.Of<ILogger<ApprovalController>>();
    controller = new ApprovalController(mockRequestRepo.Object, mockServiceRepo.Object, mockLoggerRepo);
}

[Fact]
public async Task GetPendingApprovals_HasPending_ReturnsResultAsync()
{
     // Arrange
     var mockRequests = new List<Request>
     {
         new Request { Id = 1,
             PONumber = "ABC0001",
             RequestorId = 1,
             SubmitDate = new DateTime(),
             ApproverId = 2,
             StatusId = 1,
             Split = false,
             VendorId1 = 1,
             Remarks = "
         },
         new Request { Id = 2,
             PONumber = "ABC0002",
             RequestorId = 1,
             SubmitDate = new DateTime(),
             ApproverId = 2,
             StatusId = 1,
             Split = false,
             VendorId1 = 1,
             Remarks = "
        }
     };
     mockServiceRepo.Setup (repo => repo.GetUserID ("pstaley").Returns (Task.FromResult (1);
     //var pending = mockRequests.AsEnumerable();
     mockRequestRepo.Setup (repo => repo.GetPendingApprovalsByApprover (1).Returns (Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<Request>> (mockRequests);
     // Act
     var result = await controller.GetPendingApprovals();

    // Assert
    var actionResult = Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(result);
    //Assert.Equal(mockRequests, actionResult);

}
```

Debugging the test itself it the `mockRequest` is *null* so when it goes to the controller it meets the null check and returns no content response.

Comment: Most likely `User` is null as i see no setup for that and thus the expectation of the mocks do not match and this returns null by default.

Comment: Why not use `ReturnsAsync` so you can avoid `Task.FromResult`?

Comment: It looks like the issue is that you didn't setup `GetUserName` to return `"pstaley"`.

Comment: That was it.  Thank you.  I was thinking that didn't matter since all that did was pull in the user ID that I was manually passing to the second call.  Lesson learned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely `User` is *null* as I see no setup for that and `GetUserName` is not setup to do anything so that will be null as well.

thus the expectation of the mocks do not match and this returns null by default.

Loosen the expectation on the `GetUserID` with `It.IsAny<string>()` to get the expected behavior.

```
[Fact]
public async Task GetPendingApprovals_HasPending_ReturnsResultAsync() {
    // Arrange
    var mockRequests = getUsers();
    var userId = 1;
    mockServiceRepo
        .Setup(repo => repo.GetUserID(It.IsAny<string>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(userId);

    mockRequestRepo
        .Setup(repo => repo.GetPendingApprovalsByApprover(userId))
        .ReturnsAsync(mockRequests);

    // Act
    var result = await controller.GetPendingApprovals();

    // Assert
    var actionResult = Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(result);

    //...

}

List<Request> getUsers() {
    //... omitted for brevity
}
```